# 'paged' in wp_query doesn't work

Tags: wp-query, pagination, paged

I try to add a code to my wordpress blog show previous posts(in a previous page).
I try this code but it don't work:

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'offset' => 1,
    'cat' => -22,
    'paged'=>$paged
);
$recent = new WP_Query($args);
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
// here some code to view
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link('&#8734;','next page','previous page'); ?></p></div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

it's doesn't work in `http://mydomain.com/page/2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `offset` param, so `paged` param is ignored ;)

From Codex:

> offset (int) - number of post to displace or pass over. Warning: Setting the offset parameter overrides/ignores the paged

If you want to ignore most recent post in this query, you can achieve it in two ways.

**1. Custom pagination.**

```
$ppp = get_option('posts_per_page');  // or any other method to get your posts_per_page

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'offset' => 1 + ( $paged * $ppp ),
    'cat' => -22,
    'paged'=>$paged
);
```

**2. Ignore first post**

```
$most_recent_post_id = ...;  // get the ID of most recent post
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post__not_in' => array($most_recent_post_id),
    'cat' => -22,
    'paged'=>$paged
);
```

Comment: In a page 1 I want to posts would be displayed from second post, What is solution?

Comment: Hmm, you want to ignore most recent post, right?

Comment: yes, Exactly...